# Generic type 'ReturnType' requires 1 type argument(s).ts(2314)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, flowtype

I have recently moved from Flow to Typescript and in converting some of the codebase I am been coming into several errors, most is documented or replaced by the Utility-Types package, however I cannot find documentation or answers that help me with the below code.

```
const toObject = (keys: { reduce: (arg0: (object: any, key: any) => any, arg1: {}) => void }) =>
  keys.reduce((object: any, key: string | number) => {
    const o = object;
    o[key] = undefined;

    return object;
  }, {});



export type Pick<
  Origin extends Record<string, any>,
  Keys extends ReadonlyArray<keyof Origin>
> = $ObjMapi<ReturnType<typeof toObject, Keys>, <Key>(k: Key) => $ElementType<Origin, Key>>;

export type TypeOrVoid = <T>(arg0: T) => T | void;

export type Diffable<O extends {}> = $ObjMap<O, TypeOrVoid>;
```

More specifically, the error of `Generic type 'ReturnType' requires 1 type argument(s).ts(2314)`
 on `ReturnType<typeof toObject, Keys>`

How can I reduce to 1 type argument whilst retaining the same function? There doesn't appear to be a replacement for Flow `$Call`.

Comment: I am not familiar with flow types unfortunately. Ts types are pretty flexible so there is a good chance it is possible to write those types in TS. Could you provide an explanation of  what yo want the types to do, then maybe I can help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`ReturnType<T>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypet) just takes a single type argument, the function type. In your case, the function type is `typeof toObject`. The whole TypeScript expression would be `ReturnType<typeof toObject>` and would resolve to `any` since you are returning the result of `reduce`, which is typed as `any` in your code.